# Obtener el valor de un objecto cuando se recorre en javascript y compararlo con una variable

Tags: javascript, objeto, javascript-objeto, comparaciones, javascript-metodo

actualmente tengo un problema en javascript al tratar de correr un objecto y comparar su propiedad con un booleano, el problema es el siguiente:

La funcion llamada "vegan" recibe como argumento un objeto 'invitados', en el objeto tenemos objetos que representan los invitados a una fiesta en donde todos tienen una propiedad "vegan" con un boolean.debe retornar la cantidad de invitados que son vegan.

Mi codigo:

```
function vegan(invitados) {
var ve=0;
      for(prop in invitados)
      {

       console.log(invitados[prop]);
      }
}
```

Comment: al referirte que 'invitados' es un objeto que tiene objetos te refieres a que es un array de objetos? si fuera asi puedes usar la funcion filter() que retornara una lista segun la condicion que le pongas invitados.filter(x=> x.vegan == true) y ya solo usarias lapropiedad length para obtener el numero de elementos.

Comment: es el código completo? donde está el objeto? Para ese caso deberías usar filter()

Answer (score 0):

```
      // La funcion llamada "vegan" recibe como argumento un objeto 'invitados', en el objeto tenemos objetos que representan los invitados
      // a una fiesta en donde todos tienen una propiedad "vegan" con un boolean.
      // debe retornar la cantidad de invitados que son vegan.
      // Por ej:
      // let invitados = {
      //     Luna: {
      //         vegan: false
      //     },
      //     Sebas: {
      //         vegan: false
      //     },
      //     Marce: {
      //         vegan: false
      //     },
      //     Nicky: {
      //         vegan: true
      //     }
      // };
      // vegan(invitados) devuelve 1
      // Tip: Podes usar el metodo for...in
      // Tu código aca:
      var ve= {
        vegani : true
      };
      for(prop in invitados)
      {
       if(invitados[prop]==ve.vegani)
       console.log("hola mundo");
      }
}
```

este seria el codigo completo y lo que he intentado.

Answer (score 0):

Esta publicación está escondida. Tú la eliminaste ahora mismo.
Son objetos dentro de un objeto,entonces.fiter() no podes utilizar deberia utilizar un for .. in.
algo asi:

> Cita en bloque`

<

```
 let sum = 0;
  for (let key in invitados) {
    if (invitados[key].vegan == true) {
      sum ++;
    }
  }
  return sum;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).